# alfred cannot search application

Tags: alfred

alfred cannot search application, only search web result.

I cannot find anywhere to solve it.

what can I try?

[my aflred picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZtWc.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Did you disable the spotlight index?

Alfred relies on the same OS X metadata index as Spotlight. As such, it's important for you to let Spotlight run on your Mac to maintain an index of the files on it.
Turning off Spotlight indexing will still allow you to use Alfred as a web launcher but you'll no longer be able to find files on your Mac.

Source : https://www.alfredapp.com/help/troubleshooting/indexing/spotlight/

Answer (score 1):

[alfred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRba1.png)

I think you need to check the settings in the picture, especially the `Search Scope`，you need to allow search the `macOS Applications folder`

Comment: It would be useful to list the relevant settings and explain why they would affect the searching (rather than rely on a picture only).